# PhpMyAdmin problem after upgrade Ubuntu Server 16.04 to 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, php, phpmyadmin

After doing a do-release-upgrade from Ubuntu Server 16.04 to 18.04.1 I have a problem with PhpMyAdmin. It doesn't interpret the php code and shows me the php script on `localhost/phpmyadmin/`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
PHP 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 /
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) /
phpmyadmin 4:4.6.6-5 /
mysql  Ver 14.14
```

When I run `php /var/www/html/info.php` form the command line it gives me all the correct php info. In the browser I just get:

```
?php
phpinfo();
?
```

Comment: How did you install PhpMyAdmin on 16.04.1?  Did you check that `lamp-server` and its dependencies are installed?

Comment: I installed following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04 and all was working well untill I did the release-upgrade. Apache2 is still working correctly.

Comment: Install the `libapache2-mod-phpx.x` module again perhaps it wasn't reinstalled or upgraded...

Comment: Thank you George! It turns out after the upgrade i had both libapache2-mod-php and libapache2-mod-php7.2 installed on the system. Removed both and reinstalled libapache2-mod-php7.2, that did the trick. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out after the upgrade i had both libapache2-mod-php and libapache2-mod-php7.2 installed on the system. Removed both and reinstalled libapache2-mod-php7.2.